# How to Set a Hook on IE url

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, hook

I Have a app running background. I use it to get the url on IE if the IE is running...
It's better if It is a hook not a loop enum the windows.
How can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official, non-window enuming way to do this is to author a [BHO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(VS.85).aspx), implement [IObjectWithSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768220(VS.85).aspx) and then get the IWebBrowser2 pointer from your site.  [IWebBrowser2::get_LocationUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb159748.aspx) will give you the URL.